# Hidden value is passing while the div's display style is none using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is my JS:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function display(action, id) { if
 (action == 'show') {
 document.getElementById("explanation"+id).style.display
 = "block"; document.getElementById("link"+id).href=
 "javascript:display('hide', "+id+")";
 document.getElementById("link"+id).innerHTML
 = "Close"; }

 if (action == 'hide') {
 document.getElementById("explanation"+id).style.display
 = "none"; document.getElementById("link"+id).href=
 "javascript:display('show', "+id+")";
 document.getElementById("link"+id).innerHTML
 = "Explain"; } }

 </script>
```

and HTML:

```
 <form name="test" id="test"
 method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {assign var="clone" value="0"}
     {section name=another loop=$dealImageTest}
     {assign var="cloneTemp" value=$clone++}
     <table><tr>
     <td width="121" align="left">
     <div id="explanation{$cloneTemp}" >

     <img src="{$dealImageTest[another]}"
 width="62" height="40" /><a
 id="link{$cloneTemp}"
 href="javascript:display('hide',
 {$cloneTemp})">Remove</a>

     <input type="hidden" name="dealImage_{$clone++}" id="{$dealImageTest[another]}"
 value="{$dealImageTest[another]}">

      </div>

      </td> </tr></table>

     {/section}

 </form>
```

When i click the remove button the image is hiding. But when i submit the form i am getting the hidden type's value.

But According to div if the style is hidden it will not pass any value.

How can is solve this issues. Any idea will be helpful and greatful. thanks in advance

Comment: `But According to div if the style is hidden it will not pass any value.` who told you that? It is not true

Comment: Don't give it a name if you don't want its values.

Comment: `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` don't destroy/eliminate the element. They just prevent it from being shown in the page. It's vaguely the equivalent of changing an input field's type from 'text' to 'hidden'. The field's still there, you just can't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting an input (or its container `div`) to `hidden` will not prevent the input from being sent to the server.

You would have to either physically remove the element, or set its value to `null`, when hiding the container. In order to not lose the original value, store it in a temporary variable, or a property of the input object.

Comment: Also note that adding the attribute `disabled` to an input will prevent its value from being submitted.

Answer (score 2):

All fields including hidden, are posted to web server.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately hidden fields, even into 'display:none' HTML components, are sent to the server.

A possible solution could be adding another `<input type="hidden" .../>` field and change its value when you show/hide the div, so you will be aware on server side if you need to "consider" the value of "dealImage_xxx" or not.

Comment: I said "unfortunately" because of oezi's assumption of course :-)